# Why I can't get Coords.Speed from web browers ( using mobile)?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm try this code, but speed always get Null instead "0"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude+    
  "<br>Speed: " + position.coords.speed +
  "<br>Time : " + new Date(position.timestamp) ;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can access this link http://traffic.hcmut.edu.vn/nhan/test.html to test (using mobile browser)

Comment: From specs *The speed attribute denotes the magnitude of the horizontal component of the hosting device's current velocity and is specified in meters per second. If the implementation cannot provide speed information, the value of this attribute must be null. Otherwise, the value of the speed attribute must be a non-negative real number.* Another possibility is that it's not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If the speed is not given with the data (for example is the implementation is not providing it), then you could try checking the time between different measurements, and then check the distance of teh coordinates, and use these two values for determining the speed.

Though I would suspect that the Browser engine positioning is rather inaccurate, thus you might not get too accurate speed values by using it.

Incase you are having a real mobile device in which your app is running, you might want to try out any nattive API there are for the platform for more accurate values.